# Plot of a tornado-shaped surface

Tags: plotting

What is a simple code to plot a surface shaped like a tornado?
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 18):

My quick go at it:

```
ContourPlot3D[
  (x - z/5 Cos[\[Pi] z])^2 + (y - z/5 Sin[\[Pi] z])^2 == (z/4)^2
  , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 2}
  , Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False
  , PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", ContourStyle -> RGBColor[0.41, 0.5, 0.63]
]
```

[image: Tornado]

Answer (score 18):

I like "surface synthesis" questions. Here's a simple-minded model that combines an Archimedean spiral with a power law curve:

```
With[{h = 1/10, n = 24, c = 4, p = 2/3},
     ParametricPlot3D[{t (h Cos[n t] + Cos[v]), t (h Sin[n t] + Sin[v]), (c t)^p},
                      {t, 0, 3}, {v, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                      Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 85,
                      PlotStyle -> Opacity[3/4, Black], ViewPoint -> {3.2, -1.6, 1.}]]
```

[image: tornado?]

Adjust parameters as seen fit.

Comment: (I should prolly do a cartoon of the "tornado" moving about in a random walk...)